# Moving Average Using User-Input Array

Tags: java, arrays, user-input, moving-average

I need to write a program that calculates a moving average by a user inputted array. The first element of the array is the window size, and the input is terminated by a 0. The output values are printed with two digits after the decimal point.

Example input: `3 2 4 7 7 8 11 12 0`

Corresponding Output: `4.33 6.00 7.33 8.67 10.33`

(4.33 is average of 2,4,7 and  6 is average of 4,7,7 etc.)

Here's my code so far:

```
package movingaverage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MovingAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
     }
     avg[0] = sum / 5;

    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 5; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + arr[i] - arr[i - 5];
        avg[j++] = sum / 5;
    }

  }

}
```

I think I have the loop right, but I'm not sure how to get the array to end at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution.

```
public class Test
{
   private static final Scanner SCANNER;

   static {
      SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);
   }

   public static final void main(final String... args) {
      final String[] numbers = SCANNER.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
      final int consideredElements = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
      float sum = 0;
      int value = 0;

      for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         sum = 0;

         for (int k = 0; k < consideredElements; k++) {
            value = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i + k]);

            if (value == 0) {
               return;
            }

            sum += value;
         }

         System.out.println(new BigDecimal(sum / consideredElements).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: that works, but I need it to work for a user-inputted array.

Comment: See updated answer. This accept a list of numbers separated by a space.

Comment: so for this line `final int[] numbers = Arrays.stream(SCANNER.nextLine().trim().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();` is there anyway to change that so I'm not using the array class? this assignment is for a beginner Java class and we haven't covered that topic yet.

Comment: Take a look now, If it's still not for beginner, initialize the array with a user inputted number, then use a while loop to ask the user for the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using 5 in a couple of places in your program, I see no justification for that. Could it be that your expectation of user input lead you to put 5 where the number you really should use, depends on user input? Maybe you should use the window size instead? I’m guessing a bit here.

Next, as @lppEdd pointed out, you are not reading the numbers from your input — only the window size.

Next, you are declaring your array of size `n`, which I believe was your window size, not your array size. I believe the real solution to this problem is using better and more explanatory variable names.

Your code does not compile since you have not declared the array `avg` that you try to store your moving average into.

Fifth, when you want your average as a `double`, you need to convert to `double` *before* dividing (this is a classic pitfall that has already generated many questions on Stack Overflow).

I hope this gets you a couple of steps further.

Comment: The first thing you see is that he is using nextInt(), which only returns a single integer value, not an array. Basically he would be using an array filled with zeros.

Comment: It's not mine =)

Comment: No, I thought not, @LppEdd (it came today, so likely someone who didn’t see this thread until today).